# How can I swap this switch statement into a polymorphic approach?

Tags: java, switch-statement, polymorphism

I have been reading clean code by Robert C. Martin and studying solid principles, I have noticed some code like this in my class:

```
@When("^they click the (.*) hyperlink$")
public void the_browser_opens_a_new_hyperlink(String link) {
    Runnable aSyncTask = null;
    switch (link.toLowerCase()) {
        case "cookie":
            aSyncTask =
                    () -> {
                        {
                            loginPage.openCookieInformationPage();
                            loginPage.switchToNewestTab();

                        }
                    };
            break;
        case "privacy policy":
            aSyncTask =
                    () -> {
                        {
                            loginPage.openPrivacyPolicyInformationPage();
                            loginPage.switchToNewestTab();
                        }
                    };
            break;
        case "report a problem":
            aSyncTask =
                    () -> {
                        {
                            loginPage.openReportAProblemPage();
                            loginPage.switchToNewestTab();
                        }
                    };
            break;
    }
    driverTabHelper.execAsyncTaskThatLaunchesATab(Objects.requireNonNull(aSyncTask, "invalid link specified"));
}
```

This is a clear violation of the open/closed principle because the more links I add, I will have to keep modifying this method to account for them.

As you can see, the loginPage is currently providing 3 different links as strings to this method, however there will be more objects passing in links at a later stage.

How do I rewrite this for polymorphism? I was thinking maybe have page(s) implement `IOpenHyperlink` and using the interface reference as the argument, but page(s) can provide multiple links, add an interface per link? seems excessive

Also any advice on improving the code here in general is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You could create a factory class which returns the appropriate `Runnable` given an input, but there too you would have a switch/if-else statement.  The only way AFAIK to avoid the switch completely would be to somehow use reflection to instantiate the runnable.

Comment: By the way, given that your code is already running, and you just want pointers to improve it, your question might fit better on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: woops, thanks @Tim, I will move that over

Answer (score 0):

This is a proof of concept of something you could do. This code won't compile as it is. You might want not to have a dependency injection at all and create DriverTabHelper inside the HyperLinkActivity when it is initialized.

I recommend googling: "refactoring switch statements"

```
abstract class HyperLinkActivity {
    private DriverTabHelper driverTabHelper;

    public HyperLinkActivity(DriverTabHelper driverTabHelper) {
        this.driverTabHelper = driverTabHelper;
    }

    public void startTask() {
        Runnable aSyncTask = () -> { implementation() }
        driverTabHelper.execAsyncTaskThatLaunchesATab(Objects.requireNonNull(aSyncTask, "invalid link specified"));
    }

    abstract void implementation();
}

class CookieHyperLink extends HyperLinkActivity {
    public void implementation() {
        loginPage.openCookieInformationPage();
        loginPage.switchToNewestTab();
    }
}

class HyperlinkService {
    private DriverTabHelper driverTabHelper;

    public void HyperLinkService(DriverTabHelper driverTabHelper) {
        this.driverTabHelper = driverTabHelper;
    }


    public void createCookieActivity() {
        CookieHyperLink cookieHyperLink = new CookieHyperLink(driverTabHelper);
        handleHyperLinkTask(cookieHyperLink);
    }

    public void handleHyperLinkTask(HyperLinkActivity hyperLinkActivity) {
        hyperLinkActivity.startTask();
    }
}
```